# Как сделать что бы число начинающиеся с 0 можно было добавить?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно что бы число начинающиеся с 0 можно было добавить, вот код:

```
x = eval(input())
print(x)
```

Говорю коду:`01+1`

Ответ убил:`SyntaxError: leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not permitted; use an 0o prefix for octal integers`

А мне нужно что бы вывод был: `2`

Comment: Делайте предобработку строки, удаляя такие нули. В чём проблема?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string

Comment: Ну так eval работает по правилам языка Питон, а в Питоне 0 впереди числа означает восьмеричное число.

Answer (score -2):

Как я сделал:

```
    def menu():
        phone = input()
        phone = str(phone)
        phone = int(phone)
        start(phone)
```

Comment: как это отвечает на вопрос? изложите это, пожалуйста, прямо в тексте ответа, нажав [edit]

Comment: Что за бред?  Зачем введенное значение сначала превращать в строку а потом полученную строку в число? И да, какое это имеет отношение к вопросу - абсолютно не ясно